# How to persistently install commands on a live kali bootable USB?

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb, bootable

I will be using the live kali bootable usb for work as forensic tool to image systems using dc3dd. However, it seems that dc3dd is not installed by default on the latest release of bootable usb live kali. How do i install it to the usb and make it persistent so that i dont have to install dc3dd everytime i need to image a system?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Kali linux is the wrong choice for a forensic tool. It's a one-trick pony for network security testing. So, simply choose a different Linux distro and install the tool you want on that - trivial with e.g. Ubuntu, which comes with a mechanism to add persistent storage to a live medium.

Other distros also have mature workflows to design your own live medium, integrating exactly the software you want. (again, Kali is special, and really not the system of choice here. It's good – for something completely different.)

Comment: Thanks. I guess thats why i cant find anything regarding this anywhere: because people simply use other distro. I choose Kali initially because it has "forensic mode". I suppose other distro can do this as well?